# Display google map on hover link or text

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

http://coding.pressbin.com/18/Display-a-Google-Map-when-you-hover-over-location-text/ I am following this tutorial on how to display google map over a text. Yes it appears but in a wrong place. See, the map is displaying on the bottom of the page. When I hover the map image the div itself has no attributes compared to the working ones.

Working code:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 678px; top: 170px; z-index: 999; display: none; padding: 1px; margin-left: 5px; background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51); width: 302px; box-shadow: 0pt 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
<a target="new" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Brookhaven, PA&z=11">
<img border="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brookhaven, PA&zoom=12&size=300x300&sensor=false&format=png&markers=color:blue|Brookhaven, PA">
</a>
</div>
```

What's in my browser:

```
<div style="display: none;">
<a target="new" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=4417 Edgmont Avenue, 19015&z=11">
<img border="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=4417 Edgmont Avenue, 19015&zoom=16&size=300x300&sensor=false&format=png&markers=color:blue|4417 Edgmont Avenue, 19015">
</a>
</div>
```

I'm lost on the div part.
Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what works for me:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>jQuery Test Script</title>
</head>
<body>
<span class="mapThis" place="600 Forbes Ave, Pittsburgh, PA 15282" zoom="16">Duquesne University</span> is located in the great town of <span class="mapThis" place="Pittsburgh, PA" zoom="12">Pittsburgh</span> in the great state of <span class="mapThis" place="Pennsylvania" zoom="6">Pennsylvania</span>.
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/test_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the jQuery to make it happen:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function () {
var cursorX;
var cursorY;
if (window.Event) {
  document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
}
document.onmousemove = getCursorXY;
$(".mapThis").each(function() {
  var dPlace = $(this).attr("place");
  var dZoom = $(this).attr("zoom");
  var dText = $(this).html();
  $(this).html('<a onmouseover="mapThis.show(this);" style="text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted #999" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + dPlace + '&z=' + dZoom + '">' + dText + '</a>');
 });
});
var mapThis=function(){
var tt;
var errorBox;
return{
  show:function(v){
   if (tt == null) {
   var pNode = v.parentNode;
   pPlace = $(pNode).attr("place");
   pZoom = parseInt($(pNode).attr("zoom"));
   pText = $(v).html();
   tt = document.createElement('div');
   $(tt).html('<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + pPlace + '&z=11" target="new"><img border=0 src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' + pPlace + '&zoom=' + pZoom + '&size=300x300&sensor=false&format=png&markers=color:blue|' + pPlace + '"></a>');
   tt.addEventListener('mouseover', function() { mapHover = 1; }, true);
   tt.addEventListener('mouseout', function() { mapHover = 0; }, true);
   tt.addEventListener('mouseout', mapThis.hide, true);
   document.body.appendChild(tt);    
}
fromleft = cursorX;
fromtop = cursorY;
fromleft = fromleft - 25;
fromtop = fromtop - 25;
tt.style.cssText = "position:absolute; left:" + fromleft + "px; top:" + fromtop + "px; z-index:999; display:block; padding:1px; margin-left:5px; background-color:#333; width:302px; -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);";   
tt.style.display = 'block';
},
hide:function(){
tt.style.display = 'none';
tt = null;
}
 };
}();
function getCursorXY(e) {
cursorX = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
cursorY = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
 }
```

Comment: In the tutorial example on his site, he didn't add the mouse listener to the code but, I found it in the full code.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but I thought it might be useful if anyone stumbles upon this and is looking for a more updated example.  Although the code in the answer works fine it is not written in a jQuery friendly format.  I also found that the way the event listeners were configured made it's use a little difficult.  Lastly, the fixed size of the map just does not work in today's responsive world.  Hope this helps someone!

Add `#mapHolder` anywhere in your page and style it to your liking:

```
<div id='mapHolder' style='whatever you want'></div>
```

Place links anywhere in your page that you what to display a map when moused over:

```
 <a class="mapthis" place="properly formatted address" zoom="12">MAP</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".mapthis", function(e) {
    var desiredMapWidthPercent = .8;
    var mapWidth = Math.round($(window).width() * desiredMapWidthPercent);
    var aspectRatio = mapWidth / $(window).height();
    var mapHeight = Math.round($(window).height() * aspectRatio);
    var boxWidth = mapWidth;
    var boxHeight = mapHeight;
    var scale = 1;
    var pZoom = parseInt($(this).attr("zoom"));
    var pPlace = $(this).attr("place"); 
    if((mapHeight > 640) || (mapWidth > 640)){
        mapHeight = Math.round(mapHeight / 3.5);
        mapWidth = Math.round(mapWidth / 3.5);
        scale = 2;
        if(((mapHeight) > 1280) || ((mapWidth) > 1280)){
            mapHeight = 640;
            mapWidth = 640;
            boxWidth = 1280;
            boxHeight = 1280;
        }else{
            boxWidth = mapWidth * 2;
            boxHeight = mapHeight * 2;
        }
    }
    var fromleft = Math.max(0, ((($(window).width() - boxWidth) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()))+'px';
    var fromtop = Math.max(0, ((($(window).height() - boxHeight) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()))+'px';
    var pText = $(this).html();
    $('#mapHolder').html('<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + pPlace + '&z=11" target="new"><img border=0 src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' + pPlace + '&zoom=' + pZoom + '&size='+mapWidth+'x'+mapHeight+'&scale='+scale+'&sensor=false&format=png&markers=color:blue|' + pPlace + '"></a>');
    $('#mapHolder').css({position:'absolute',top:fromtop,left:fromleft, width:boxWidth, z-index:'999'});
    $('#mapHolder').show();
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".mapthis", function(e) {
    if($(e.relatedTarget).closest('#mapHolder').length){
        $("#mapHolder").on("mouseleave", function(e) {
            $('#mapHolder').hide();
        });
        return;
    }
    $('#mapHolder').hide();            
});
```